# cannot able to download the file in a webview

Tags: android, android-webview

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Also try adding Permission for **Read and Write external storage** and should use **Runtime permission for read-write permission**